# Bound for number of points on surface over $\mathbb{F}_p$

Tags: number-theory, elliptic-curves, arithmetic-geometry

I know of the bound for the number of points on an elliptic curve over a finite field:
$$|\# E(\mathbb{F}_q) - q - 1| < 2\sqrt{q}$$
where this includes the point at infinity.  I have been told that there are higher analogues of this formula which involve $q^{(k-1)/2}$ (instead of $q^{1/2}$ here), but I know very little about the theory so I'm not exactly sure what the $k$ is and all that.  Can any one help me out with the formula for this?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\char}{char}$The general form that this bound takes is known under the term [Weil conjectures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures), which is a theorem of Deligne. Here is how it goes.

If $X$ is a non-singular $n$-dimensional projective variety over $\mathbb{F}_q$, (an elliptic curve is the special case $n=1$), then you collect information about the number $N_m$ of points of $X$ over $\mathbb{F}_{q^m}$ for all $m$ in the generating function
$$
\zeta(X, s) = \exp\left(\sum_{m = 1}^\infty \frac{N_m}{m} (q^{-s})^m\right).
$$
This is known as the zeta function of $X$.

The Weil conjectures then say that $\zeta(X, s)$ is a rational function of $T = q^{−s}$, and can be written as
$$
\prod_{i=0}^{2n} P_i(q^{-s})^{(-1)^{i+1}} = \frac{P_1(T)\dotsb P_{2n-1}(T)}{P_0(T)\dotsb P_{2n}(T)},
$$
where each $P_i(T)$ is an integral polynomial. Let $P_i$ factor over $\mathbb{C}$ as $\prod_j (1 - \alpha_{i,j}T)$. If $X$ came from a projective variety defined over a number field with good reduction at $p=\char \mathbb{F}_q$, then the degree of the $i$-th polynomial is the $i$-th Betty number of $X$. Moreover,
$P_0(T) = 1 − T$ and $P_{2n}(T) = 1 − q^nT$. The Riemann hypothesis for these varieties, which is part of Weil's conjectures, says that
$$|\alpha_{i,j}| = q^{i/2},$$
and this is the source of the Hasse bound you just cited. Here is what happens in your special case.

Let's assume for the moment that $X$ is a curve, so $n=1$. The degree of $P_1$ is twice the genus $g$ of the curve. If you take the logarithmic derivative of the zeta function, do some rearranging, and compare the coefficients of $T$, you will find that
$$
N_m = 1 + q^m - (\alpha_{1,1}^m+\cdots+\alpha_{1,2g}^m),
$$
which gives you the bound $|N_m - q^m - 1|\leq 2g\sqrt{q}^m$ that you quoted in the special case $g=1$.

If $X$ is a higher dimensional variety, then you can try to do the same manipulations, but I believe that the expression for $N_m$ will be less clean. Nevertheless, you should get something to the effect that $N_m = q^{nm} + O(q^{(2n-1)m/2})$. So your $k$ is my $2n$.

Comment: Dear Alex, I think that the bound in the last line actually goes back to Lang--Weil (and in particular, predates Deligne).  (You can get it by fibreing a higher dimensional variety by curves, or something similar, and using the Hasse--Weil bound for curves.)  Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt Dear Matthew, thank you, that's very interesting! If you have time to write your comment up as an answer at some point or to provide a reference, I would be very interested.

Comment: Dear Alex, See e.g. Theorem 2.1 of [these notes by Mustata](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~mmustata/lecture7.pdf) (where you can also find a reference to the original paper).  Best wishes,

Comment: @Matt Dear Matt, wonderful, thank you! Best wishes,

Comment: @AlexB. In your expression of $N_m$, I don't know why the first subscript of these $\alpha$ are all $1$. If you take the logarithm first, then you have $\sum \frac{N_m}{m}T^m=InP_1+...InP_{2n-1}-InP_0-...-InP_n$, then take the derivative, you will get $N_1+N_2T+N_3T^2+...=\frac{P_1'}{P_1}+...-\frac{P_0'}{P_0}$, let $t=0$, then $N_1=-\sum_{i,j} \alpha_{i.j}$. But how to get your formula $N_1=1+q-\alpha_{1,1}-...-\alpha_{1,2g}$? Thanks!

Comment: @Sssss: do not set $t=0$. Instead, expand the rational functions on the RHS of your equality as power series, and compare the coefficients of $T^m$ for each $m$. Remember that for curves, there are only three polynomials, $P_0$, $P_1$, and $P_2$, and you know $P_0$ and $P_2$ (as explained in the answer). When you expand the resulting rational functions as power series, the $1$ will come from $P_0$, the $q^m$ will come from $P_2$, and the remaining sum of the $\alpha$s will come from $P_1$.

Answer (score 1):

I think what's going on is if you have an equation in $k$ variables over a field of $q$ elements then you expect it to have $q^{k-1}$ solutions and the error term, under suitable hypotheses, is some constant multiple of $q^{(k-1)/2}$.